# Multicore license: ESX Vs Citrix Xenserver

Tags: vmware-esx, licensing, citrix, xenserver, multi-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

VMware ESX is free for upto 6 cores per CPU only

Vsphere Advanced version is required for 12 CPU cores

does Xenserver 5.5 free support greater than 6 cores per CPU/Socket?

Comment: @John: not duplicate. your question sounds too generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From: http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/22761-102-642263/XenServer_5_5_2_FAQ_Feb_2010.pdf

- **Does XenServer support dual-core or greater processors?**

  Yes, XenServer supports multi-core processors.
- **How many processors can XenServer utilize?**

  All XenServer Editions can utilize up to 32 cores total per system.

There isn't a limit on the number of cores per socket, just cores per host.

Answer (score 1):

Just beware that there's  a core-per-socket setting in XenServer, only available to paid versions of XenServer. Also, if you're using Windows vms, you've to make sure that there are cpu socket limits on Windows editions.

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126524